# how to bind silverlight pivotgrid to wcf data service?

Tags: devexpress, wcf-data-services, silverlight-5.0

I am creating an application in which i want to get data from wcf service and want to bind it with devexpress 12.2 pivotgrid control.

Can any one help me or point me to link or tutorial for the same ?

Thanks & Regards,
Rudresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could start from these:

- [How to: Build a Service for Silverlight Clients](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197940%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)
- [Using WCF Web Services With Silverlight (and LINQ)](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2009/07/07/day-7-using-wcf-web-services-with-silverlight-and-linq/)
- [Using WCF Service with Silverlight](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/262164/Using-WCF-Service-with-Silverlight) - this one is a bit more advanced (and complete!), so read it after the first two

Good Luck!